# How to split json dataset and save it?

Tags: python, json, split, pytorch

I have taken a json dataset. Dataset name is **v2_OpenEnded_mscoco_train2014_questions.json** How can I split some of the data from the dataset and save the split data into another json file?

This is the example of my dataset:

> {"image_id": 426004, "question": "How many buns are on the plate?",
> "question_id": 426004002}, {"image_id": 92846, "question": "What is
> the color of the vase without flowers?", "question_id": 92846000},
> {"image_id": 92846, "question": "Is there anything red in this
> photo?", "question_id": 92846002}, {"image_id": 92846, "question":
> "What does that vase represent?", "question_id": 92846003},
> {"image_id": 262166, "question": "What color is the couch?",
> "question_id": 262166002}, {"image_id": 262166, "question": "How many
> seats are available?", "question_id": 262166003}

I have about **443,757 data** in my dataset. I want to split the dataset into **400 different dataset** each having **100 data**. How can I automate this using python?
It will be a great help if this can be done with pytorch.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe put it into a pandas DataFrame and write blocks of that to json, or use the json as a list of dictionaries and enumerate them to loop through in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
n_rows = 100
current_data = []
for i, e in enumerate(data):
    if i % n_rows == 0 and i > 0:
        with open(f'dataset_{i - n_rows}-{i}.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(current_data, f)
        current_data = []
    
    current_data.append(e)
```

`data` is a list with jsons which you have. We iterate over it and every `n_rows` lines are written in a new file. The last several rows aren't written.